# Post to facebook page stream programmatically

Tags: php, facebook, api

My facebook user is the admin for several facebook pages.  What I am trying to do is post to the feed of one of these pages from an external php website automatically.  For instance, when something interesting happens on the site, publish a notification to the news stream of the page.

I have created an application in facebook, and I am using the php fb api like this:

```
//actual values redacted, obviously
$appId = 'my_app_id';
$pageId = 'my_page_id';
$secret = 'my_app_secret';

//First i'm getting the authtoken
$args = array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $appid,
    'client_secret' => $secret
);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//this comes back from facebook like auth_token=xxxxx
$token = str_replace("access_token=", "", $data); //remove 'auth_token='


$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $appId,
        'secret' => $secret,
        'cookie' => false,
        'domain' => 'mydomain.net'
    ));


$facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", 'post', array(           
    'access_token' => $token,
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com'
));
```

This connects to facebook and attempts to publish to the feed, but fails saying:

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

So my question is, how am I supposed to authorize the application to publish to the feed?  I don't see any setting on the app, and there appears to be no way to "add" permissions to the page. I am totally lost at this point, and the facebook documentation is not much help.

Any help would be really appreciated. I've lost a whole day on this.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the $token parameter from this array

```
$facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", 'post', array(           
    **'access_token' => $token,**
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com'
));
```

and set the token this way before the POST API call

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($token);
```

let me know how it did

Comment: same result as before, it complains saying The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, how am I supposed to authorize the application to publish to the feed? I don't see any setting on the app, and there appears to be no way to "add" permissions to the page.

You have to get an **access token** first – either a *user access token* (the long-lived ones expire after 60 days, so you’d have to come back to your app regularly to renew it), or a *page access token* (doesn’t expire by default). And you’ll have to ask for the necessary **permission** to post (when acting on behalf of a user).

To get them, you have to go through the authentication flow. All the details are described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

What might also be helpful, if you’re not too familiar with using the API yet, might be the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) – there you can “play around”, make different kinds of requests, see what the outcomes or errors are. And it lets you generate user access tokens there (to give you an idea what you will have to do in your app yourself).